# Error when importing a react module when using either Jest or Mocha for testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocha.js, ts-jest

Currently, I'm trying to unit test some react components, but I am hitting issues when importing react modules.

The error I'm hitting is the following

```
    C:\Users\Andrew.Urry\source\Workspaces\Empower\PlatformAdmin\Portal\node_modules\mpx-error-boundary\ErrorBoundary.js:2
    import * as React from 'react';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       6 | import { PageHeader } from './SubMenu';
       7 | import { msg } from 'mpx-multi-language';
    >  8 | import { ErrorBoundary } from 'mpx-error-boundary';
```

jest.config.js file is the following:

```
module.exports = {
    "roots": [
        "<rootDir>/wwwroot/ts-tests"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
    ],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
}
```

package.json file is the following:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.3.2",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/sinon": "^9.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "esm": "3.2.25",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.13.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "mocha": "^8.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "sinon-chai": "3.5.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "26.2.0",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-node-register": "1.0.0",
    "jest": "26.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-table": "^1.16.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.11",
    "material-table": "^1.68.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "mpx-dialog": "^1.1.12",
    "mpx-error-boundary": "^1.0.0",
    "mpx-multi-language": "^1.0.8",
    "mpx-react-page-components": "^1.0.6",
    "mpx-utilities": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "tableexport.jquery.plugin": "^1.10.20"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/mpx-error-boundary/"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
    }
  },
  "mocha": {
    "extension": [
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "spec": "wwwroot/ts-tests/**/*.test.tsx",
    "require": [
      "wwwroot/ts-tests/babel-register.js",
      "ignore-styles"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "pack-dev": "webpack --mode development --progress",
    "pack-dev-profile": "webpack --mode development --verbose --profile --progress",
    "pack-prod": "webpack --mode production",
    "pack-library": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.library.config.js",
    "clean": "del /Q /F .\\wwwroot\\dist\\*.*"
  }
}
```

babel-register.js file is the following:

```
/* Copyright (©) Metapraxis Ltd, 2020 - 2020, all rights reserved */

// This cannot be done on the command line or in package.json due to this issue:
// https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8962

const register = require('@babel/register').default;
register({
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
});
```

tsconfig.json is the following:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "ES6",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./../Abstractions/*.d.ts",
        "./../Abstractions/**/*.d.ts",
        "./Models/*.d.ts",
        "./wwwroot/ts/*",
        "./wwwroot/ts-tests/**/*.test.ts",
        "./wwwroot/ts-tests/**/*.test.tsx"
    ]
}
```

I believe it's an issue with a mismatch between import styles, but I haven't been able to fix the issue. The package.json includes **mocha**, but it is currently using **jest** to test. Both **mocha** and **jest** hit the same issue, so it must be independent to the testing framework.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT #1: The import it's complaining about is present in an external NPM package**

**EDIT #2: I believe the issue is related to babel not transpiling the ES6 module to ES5 for testing**

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be tight with the `transformIgnorePatterns` which stated in `package.json`. Try following trick and see whether is it solve your problem.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(react|mpx-error-boundary)/)"
]
```

Comment: It's in an NPM package, but a package that I can change. I guess I could just change the NPM package, and have that call **import React from "react"?**

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I'm still getting the same error from the JavaScript file, relating to the import.

Comment: Tried that as well, and that also didn't work. Hmmm... I'll keep looking at the module import functionality.